# Why is this custom program named AQZZ...?

Tags: transactions, report, code-generation, abap, sap-query

I found a 'Z' transaction calling a program not in the customer space.
This program "seems" to be something developed by the customer, meaning its name is
"AQZZZFI_ABC=====ZPYORD========", where "ABC" is the name of the company, and the creator of the program is one of the consultants there.

What could this program be doing outside of customer namespace?
Is it auto-generated?

And if so, what framework generated it, and how can i get to the "real" development object?

Note: this program uses a logical database called "__S".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programs prefixed with `AQ` are usually generated by [SAP Query](http://help.sap.com/erp2005_ehp_04/helpdata/en/05/2b1df9209411d6b1d500508b6b8b11/frameset.htm) or the [Quick Viewer](http://help.sap.com/erp2005_ehp_04/helpdata/en/b7/26dde8b1f311d295f40000e82de14a/frameset.htm).

Comment: Now suppose the user who created the Query isn't my user. My user doesn't have any query created, so I guess I musst see his queries in order to see what my program does. Is there a way to do this without logging on with his username?

Comment: Is it a Query or a Quick View? For Quick Views, the answer is no; for Queries, I don't know...

Comment: well then that settles the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can (roughly) parse out the beginning of that string:

"AQZZ" is the SAP namespace for customer SAP Queries. So technically that naming convention is OK and is created automagically via transaction SQ01.

For the most part, SAP Queries don't but the underlying infoset that a query relies on for data might. Once you've determined the appropriate infoset for your SAP Query, you can browse any existing customer code by entering the infoset in transaction SQ02 and clicking the 'Description' button. This will show you all custom code, fields, etc.